# I write Angularjs Material Datepicker code and I got every time this - Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, angularjs-material

My datepicker code is here. I used Angularjs and Material. I got this error below:

> angular.js:88 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24HashMapProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24HashMap%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24mdUtil%20%3C-%20%24mdTheming%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue

Code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Datepicker</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.5/angular-material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.5/angular-material.js"></script>
```

```
<section aoyout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate1" md-placeholder="START DATE" ms-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate2" md-current-view="year" md-placeholder="END DATE"></md-datepicker>
</section>


<script type="text/javascript">
    angular
        .module("myApp", ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
                    .controller('myCont', function(){
                        this.myDate = new Date();
                        this.isOpen = false;
                    });

</script>
```

Comment: please update the error log clearer. But I can give you a hint that this relates to order of script import or wrong format of dependancy injection

Comment: It might help if you use the **same version** for all of the Angular dependencies.